# Spring boot REST service Kafka topic not able to consume specified number of messages

Tags: spring-boot, rest, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a simple Spring boot service that is called on-demand and consumes specified number of messages from the topic. Number of messages to consume is passed as a parameter. Service is being called every 30 minutes. Each message size is ~1.6 kb. When I call a service and pass a parameter of 3000 I am expecting 3000 thousand messages to be returned, but I always get around 1100 or 1200 messages every-time. I have one topic with one partition only. It's a on-demand service so not using while loop and have set poll time to 30 secs. But the response comes back within 10 seconds and the number of records returned is ~1200 even though MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG is 3000, 4000 or 5000. Just curious if there's any size limit on the messages even though poll time is 30 sec, how can I achieve more throughput or close to the limit. Below gets executed every time a service is called. here is how the service is called **http://example.com/messages?limit=5000**

```
Properties p = new Properties();
//limit is the value coming in as a query paramter and can be 3000, 4000 or 5000
p.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, limit);
p.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG , 15000);
p.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MIN_BYTES_CONFIG , 22 * 1024 * 1024);
p.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MIN_BYTES_CONFIG , 50 * 1024 * 1024);
p.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_WAIT_MS_CONFIG , 500);
p.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG , 50 * 1024 * 1024);

consumer = consumerFactory.createConsumer("my-group-id", null, null, p);
consumer.assign(Collections.singleton(new TopicPartition("test-topic", 0)));


ConsumerRecords<Object, Object> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(30));

// processing the messages somehow I always get ~1200 messages 
.........................................
.........................................
.................................
consumer.commitAsync();

// return list of messages
```

Thanks

Comment: You are setting `ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MIN_BYTES_CONFIG` twice and it ends up with having a same configuration value with `ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG`. Are you sure that your messages takes 1,6 kb?

Comment: I changed it but still the same affect can't consumer more than 1200 messages  p.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_BYTES_CONFIG , 50 * 1024 * 1024); My message size is 1.6kb to 2 kb range.